# Ipv6 configuration in VPS Server

Tags: networking, ipv6

Currently I have a VPS where I use different ips as interfaces, like curl google.com --ipv4 --interfaces venet0:1

The vps has ipv4 and some ipv6. Usually the vps are managed with OpenVZ, Xen, or any of these that automatically generate interfaces configurations.

This is my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto lo iface lo inet loopback

auto venet0 iface venet0 inet manual

    up ifconfig venet0 up
    up ifconfig venet0 127.0.0.2
    up route add default dev venet0
    down route del default dev venet0
    down ifconfig venet0 
down iface venet0 inet6 manual

    up ifconfig venet0 add 2607:ff28:0:a::XXXX:XXXX/128

    down ifconfig venet0 del 2607:ff28:0:a::XXXX:XXXX/128
    up ifconfig venet0 add 2607:ff28:0:a::XXXX:XXXX/128
    down ifconfig venet0 del 2607:ff28:0:a::XXXX:XXXX/128
    up route -A inet6 add default dev venet0
    down route -A inet6 del default dev venet0 
auto venet0:0 iface venet0:0 inet static

    address 173.213.XX.XX
    netmask 255.255.255.255
```

(here come the successive venet0:1 venet0:2, etc depending on ipv4 that are available.)

When using the ipv4 through interfaces, there is not problem. The case is that I want to use the ipv6 interfaces like style venet0:X.

It's possible? How I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you would paste your `interfaces` file again, and try to do it correctly this time. Your file as shown above is either broken as-is, or you pasted it incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the help. About my problem, someone knows anything?

Comment: Did you even _read_ my comment?!